Changing Checkbox Icon to Checkmark in Pop-up Menu
I'm currently working with a checkable pop-up menu and I'd like to replace the default checkbox icon (☑) with a checkmark icon (✓) on the right side of each menu item.

checkbox icon (☑)


checkmark icon (✓)


Here's the relevant part of my current code:
priority_menu.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_high_priority"
            android:title="@string/high_priority"
            android:icon="?attr/flagIcon"
            android:checkable="true" />
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_medium_priority"
            android:title="@string/medium_priority"
            android:icon="?attr/flagIcon"
            android:checkable="true" />
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_low_priority"
            android:title="@string/low_priority"
            android:icon="?attr/flagIcon"
            android:checkable="true" />
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_no_priority"
            android:title="@string/no_priority"
            android:icon="?attr/flagNoFillIcon"
            android:checkable="true" />
    </group>
</menu>

Kotlin code
private fun priorityImageButtonClicked() {
    val popupMenu = PopupMenu(requireContext(), binding.priorityImageButton)
    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.priority_menu)

    val menuPopupHelper = MenuPopupHelper(requireContext(), popupMenu.menu as MenuBuilder, binding.priorityImageButton);
    menuPopupHelper.setForceShowIcon(true)
    menuPopupHelper.show()
}

Do you know how I can change the checkbox icon to a checkmark in the pop-up menu?

Did you find the solution? @Cheok

Create res/drwable/checkmark.xml, where @drwable/ic_checkmark is your checkmark image
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkmark" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>

In themes.xml (or styles.xml, whatever your project defines the styles), create a custom pop up menu style
<style name="myPopupMenuStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/checkmark</item>
</style>

Apply the style to your popupMenu
val wrapper = ContextThemeWrapper(requireContext(), R.style.myPopupMenuStyle)
val popupMenu = PopupMenu(wrapper, binding.priorityImageButton)

